# Personal site/blog, my desired .com/.net are taken

Tags: domains

I want to start to have a place on the internet I can call my own. Stack Exchange, Google+, and Twitter are nice, but they're all services where I have to play by their rules and I don't really own my own content. So I've decided that I really need my own site.

The problem is, my desired `.com`/`.net` domains are taken. If it matters, my desired domain involves my name.

- Will people have difficulty remembering or typing a less common extension and/or will I be judged in a less favorable light if I don't have a `.com`/`.net`?
- If not, which extension would be best for a personal site? `.org`, `.co`, `.me`, `.us`, and many others are available?

Comment: I use `.info` for mine. It's "information" about me, so I think this works really well.

Comment: `kcronin.net` would still be available. The .com's gone, though.

Comment: Have you considered buying the domain from the current owner? For example, the domain I wanted, <mylastname>.com was taken but after some investigation, it turns out it was abandoned by the owner - because they got married and changed their name. They were happy to sell it to me at the average normal domain name price.

Answer (score 5):

My experience is the perception of owning a `.com` or `.co.uk` (I am UK based) seem to be taken a bit more "seriously" by the average Joe Bloggs. I think it's familiarity, `.com` and `.co.uk` are used in company TV and radio adverts every day, so could be considered "trusted".

Maybe you could consider using the extension as part of your name for example, `kylecron.in`?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking w/r/t .com, that it's taken more seriously by average people. I've definitely considered something like kylecron.in, but .in is the TLD for India. There's nothing wrong with India, I'm just thinking it might be better to avoid associating myself with other countries.

Answer (score 3):

`.name` TLD fits nicely. And if you'll have  good site, you can don't worry about top-domain

Comment: .name is definitely a possibility, but it seems a little self-referential ("<name>.name")

Comment: Isn't that the point?

Comment: self-referential?! No... My wife have _name_.net for all your old-netizen-life, _name_.name for all every-day-offline notes, _name_.pro for obvious reasons - and none is over

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against using a different suffix (such as `.org`) for a domain that is already taken, because even if you get it for the URL you want users will constantly be trying `.com` or `.net` and missing you anyway. Thus I recommend trying to find a slight variation with which to brand yourself online, such as `cronincontent.com` or something like that.

Comment: This is actually a really good point. I'm kind of hoping the existing owner of the domains lets them lapse (they're currently unused) but there's no guarantee of that.

Comment: If the existing domains are unused you could try to use something like WHOIS to contact the owner... Of course, the more interested you appear the higher they may try to sell it to you. But if they're not using it or planning to it's a waste of money for them to keep it so they may have an interest in selling it at some price.

Answer (score 3):

You can still get a `.com`/`.net`/`.org` you just need to be creative. Put a hyphen in the phrase or add descriptiors like:

```
bestsite.com
best-site.com
thebestsite.com
```

Answer (score 2):

`.org`s are very common, especially for non-commercial sites, so I would have thought there is no drawback in using the `.org` version.

Comment: I always thought .org was associated with organizations... How come that is associated with being non-commercial?

Comment: Yeah, .org at least is a recognizable TLD to normal people, and for that reason it's probably the one I'm going to go with. It is a little odd to have a personal site whose domain makes it seem like I'm an organization, but just as ".com" frequently is used for non-commercial sites and people understand that, I could probably get away with .org

Answer (score 2):

Top level domains are becoming less relevant everyday.  Especially starting out with a new site, people will find your page via links, social media, search engines or bookmarks.  Even a established, high traffic site with a short URL will only generate 10-15% of their traffic via direct input.  And by that time, your brand will be strong enough for users to remember it!

Comment: True, and internet-savvy people usually don't have a problem with different TLDs anyhow. I fully agree that whatever I do end up picking I should just stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

The `.me` tld was created specifically for individual branding. I don't think it's necessarily important to have the "common" tlds as it is a function of branding. If you are good at letting people know that your online presence is `http://kylecronin.me`, then it won't matter what the extension is.

Comment: Yeah, this is a strong contender - also, I live in Maine (ME) so .me is a good fit there too.

Comment: "The .me tld was created specifically for individual branding. " -- NO: .me is the Internet country code top-level domain for Montenegro.

Comment: @Osvaldo, Agreed. .me is tld fom montenegro. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are some relevant questions on our sister site *User Experience SE*:

- [User perception on non “.com” top level domains](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/23549/17023)

  > Should I stick with the "standard" or are there statistics that say otherwise ?
- [Does a country specific top level domain (TLD) affect perception of a (non-US) community site?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/41938/17023)

  > […] if presented with two equally relevant search results, will users tend to prefer the site that has a country-specific top level domain (.com.au say) over the one sporting a generic domain (.com)?
- [Is domain name important for user experience?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/31180/17023)

  > Is it important for the domain of a website to be chosen so that it is simple to type?
- [Are Domain Hacks usable?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/14867/17023)

  > The resulting names are cute, but are they usable?

My personal perspective: I (not from USA) associate `.com` with commercial companies resp. ad-based services (domains using `.org` or `.net` get more initial credit of trust from me.). Whenever I see a personal site using `.com`, it feels slightly inappropriate to me. Also, I don’t assume `.com` to be the "default" TLD when I only remember the second level domain name.

When I chose my personal domain, I had the following criteria:

- don’t use my name (as it [might change](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_change); and there are possibly others with the same name)
- don’t use the ccTLD of my country (as I might move)
- don’t use any other ccTLD (as it would give the wrong first impression that I’m a citizen of that country)
- don’t use any second level domain that is already registered with other TLDs (as visitors might end up at the wrong site; and I don’t want to be associated with other sites when people search for *my* term)
- pronounceable as one word in my language *and* in English
- it shouldn’t be embarrassing to write this domain on business cards etc., even in 30 years from now
- no `.com` (see above), no `.info` (bad record), no `.name` (see above re. name) … so in the end, `.org` vs. `.net`